# Call to a member function execute() on a non-object updating ammount

Tags: php

I recently had a custom URL Shortening script made, but I've been having an issue with it. It tracks the # of clicks on URLs using this script:

```
<?php
function curPageName() {
 return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}


$pagenam = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$moo = pathinfo($pagenam,PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$wof = str_ireplace("/urls/","",$moo);
$woof = str_ireplace("/","",$wof);
include("../../connect.php");
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM url WHERE refer = '$woof'");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchObject();
$clicks = $result->clicks;
$clicks++;
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE url SET clicks = '$clicks', date = NOW() WHERE refer = '$woof'");
$statement->execute();

?>
```

However, whenever a URL is clicked, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   execute() on a non-object in
>   /home/kgoco/public_html/ping.php on
>   line 18

Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can see the site in action at http://kgo.co -  Thank you in advance.

Comment: moo, wof and woof, great variable names

Comment: It seems that your $db->prepare(...) method does not return an object, therefore $statement->execute() can't be called. Could you provide a var_dump($statement); after you have called $statement = $db->prepare(...)? Then we could see what the prepare() method returns.

Comment: What database library are you using?

Comment: @Martin Matysiak, I am quite new to PHP, would you possibly mind explaining how I could do this? Also, please note that in my original post, I forgot to add the last line of code that is giving the actual error "$statement->execute();" - without it, the URL redirects fine, but does not update the clicks in the database.

Comment: @Jodes, Unfortunately, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, just add the line: `var_dump($statement)` just between you `$statement = $db->prepare(...)` and `$statement->execute();`. Then some output gets printed when you run the script. There you can see if an actual object is in the $statement field or if a null or something else got returned. Additionally, as @Jodes mentioned, it would help to know which DB Library you are using.

Comment: After putting the `$var_dump($statement);` in, I received this error: `bool(false)
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/kgoco/public_html/ping.php on line 20`

Comment: If it would help, I can upload the relevant files for analysis.

Comment: It would appear it is using the PDO library.

Comment: Stick a line near where you initialize `$db`...have it say `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`.  PDO will then throw an exception telling you what the error was, which is a lot more helpful than `false`.  (It's also less ignorable, cause it will make your script die right then and there.  But i generally prefer to have stuff that's bound to fail, fail as early and as loudly as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying to you that you cannot call `execute()` if `$statement` is not an object.
If `$statement` is not an object, then this part of your code is returning `FALSE`:

`$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM url WHERE refer = '$woof'");`,

So, after this line, you should type in the following:
`var_dump($statement);`,
to see what it is *actually* returning.